# Double Item on Action bar when click back in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I made an application using navigation drawer, open the drawer when I display the "Settings" menu

when showing the fragment in my container displays two menu "settings" and "search information".
http://saifulhq.wordpress.com/?attachment_id=242

but when i click the back button on the header and then appeared drawer, 3 items such as pictures "Setting", "Setting", "Search Information"
http://saifulhq.wordpress.com/?attachment_id=243

My question is how to remove a menu item from a fragment then add menu items from the drawer?

The following is the code on the drawer to display menu items

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar.
    // See also
    // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the
    // action bar.
    if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
        showGlobalContextActionBar();
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

this is showGlobalContextActionBar()

```
/**
 * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to
 * show the global app 'context', rather than just what's in the current
 * screen.
 */
private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for what you are doing to work you must move your menu creation to [onPrepareOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) as that is the method that is called every time your menu is created because OnCreateOptionsMenu() is only called once.

In order to remove a menu item from the menu just save the menu and call [removeItem()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#removeItem%28int%29)

Here is a reference http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#ChangingTheMenu

Comment: thang's, with moving code to OnPrepare and menu.clear() i am resolve this problem